# configurable products for a whole lot of options - text field?

Tags: magento, attributes, product, configurable

I'm trying to set up attributes for a furniture store - each desk has different dimensions, and I'd like to have width, height and length to be available in faceted navigations. As I understand, it's not possible to use text fields for faceted navigation, right?

But in this case, I assume would have to add all possible dimensions (even of products I don't need right now) so that they can then be selected when uploading the products or, whenever I'm adding a product to the CSV file, I'd need to cross-check if there is a corresponding length already stored as a value or if not, create it.

Is there a simpler way to do this? It seems just too complicated to me ... I would have expected to use "text fields" for the attribute and that the faceted navigation then grabs all the entered values from the text fields ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you solve this problem? If so any help on this problem would be appreciated :). I've asked the generic question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36091/creating-a-configurable-product-with-indefinite-attribute-value-e-g-length-wi

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your answer,  you can modify and create your own attribute type. I would possibly call it dimension.  Referenced below is an example I used to create an infinitely variable attribute that is sortable.   Sorry I'm new to actually responding on here, so if this is not supposed to be an answer please correct me.  However the link below should be of great help on this problem.

[Magento - How to create "decimal" attribute type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043457/magento-how-to-create-decimal-attribute-type)